# Matplotlib animation doesn't allow me to create bottoms and tops Line2D

Tags: python, animation, matplotlib

I have a program that makes an animation with matplotlib with a line and then errorbars (verticals)
I start my empty stuff with this

```
errorline_g, ( bottomsg,topsg ), (vertsg, ) = ax.errorbar([],
[],yerr=1,fmt='-o',color='green')
```

It has always worked but now(updated to latest ubuntu) I have an error:

```
ValueError: need more than 0 values to unpack
```

if I try 
    errorline_g, caplineg, barlinecolg  = ax.errorbar([],
    [],yerr=1,fmt='-o',color='green')

```
print errorline_g
```

Line2D(_line9)c

> print caplineg, barlinecolg

() ()

Those are two empty tuples btw and then I can't set data anymore with the tuples.

Was there any major change in matplotlib that resulted in this?
How can I update my code to work?

Thanks for any help in advance!!

JM

Comment: Please show your entire code, preferably with some made-up data - see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for the creation of a MCVE.

Comment: I fixed it. Instead of [ ] I used the first values in the list that are plotted after. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Aparently it can't be an empty list anymore. I added some values. And I no longer have that error.